# Google Talk/XMPP audio support in Python

Tags: python, audio, xmpp, google-talk

I'm looking for a Python library to communicate with Google Talk that can handle audio chat. There are plenty of them that can do text-only, but I can't find any that support audio or video. Does anyone know of one?

Comment: I believe video (and audio?) in google is powered by Vidyo.  Maybe look for python-Vidyo compatibility?

http://www.vidyo.com/

Answer (score -1):

You need a library in Python that has bindings for jingle, which is the standard for voice over xmpp. There are [build instructions](http://libjingle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README) available to create Python bindings.